# How to create table with both forward and backward information for edges with igraph

Tags: r, igraph

I have created a table with `igraph` listing the data as follows :

[image]

where a,b,c,d,e are the edges.
a and b are mutual edges, 
with the weight values of 1 for a->b, 2 for b->a (There is no self-loop).

---

By the way I used the following code to create the above table:

```
library(igraph)
library(dplyr)

g <- data.frame(from = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), 
                to = c("b", "a", "a", "b", "a"), weight = c(1:5)) %>% 
  igraph::graph_from_data_frame()
```

---

Now I hope to create another table listing both the forward and backward information between the edges, as well as the weight values like:

[image]

Does anyone know how to do this with `igraph`?

Comment: Please don't share data as pictures. People can't copy that in to their R session.

Comment: How are you determining which rows to keep? Why did you choose "from c to a" and not "from a to c". Do you not necessarily want a unique solution?

Answer (score 1):

First you could get a list of the pairs of node that share and edge regardless of direction

```
simplified <- as.undirected(g, mode="collapse")
pairs <- ends(simplified, E(simplified))
```

Then we can write a helper function to return a given edge weight between two node and if it doesn't exist, return NA instead

```
get_edge_weight<- Vectorize(function(a, b) {
  e <- E(g)[a %->% b]
  if(length(e)==1) {
    e$weight
  } else {
    NA
  }
})
```

Then you can build your desired data.frame with

```
data.frame(from=pairs[,1], to=pairs[,2],
    fwd=get_edge_weight(pairs[,1], pairs[,2]),
    back=get_edge_weight(pairs[,2], pairs[,1])
)
#   from to fwd back
# b    a  b   1    2
# c    a  c  NA    3
# d    b  d  NA    4
# e    a  e  NA    5
```

Comment: It`s been very helpful, Thanks so much !